# Validating if there is a linear transformation $S:\mathbb{R}^{3}\mapsto\mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that:

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^{3}\mapsto\mathbb{R}^{3}$ be a linear transformation such that $T\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}x_1-x_2\\ x_2-x_3\\ 
x_3-x_1\end{pmatrix}$

Is there a linear transformation $S:\mathbb{R}^{3}\mapsto\mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that:

$(T\circ S)\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-2\\ 0\\ 
2\end{pmatrix}$  and $(T\circ S)\begin{pmatrix}-2\\ 0\\2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 
2\end{pmatrix}$

Hey guys!, how should one approach such question? I am trying to reach a contradiction, however I can't manage to put my hand on one.

Comment: Note that if $T(x,y,z)=(a,b,c)$ then $a+b+c=0$.

Comment: So there isn't such S because $(T\circ S)\begin{pmatrix}-2\\ 0\\2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 
2\end{pmatrix}$ and  $0 + 1 + 2 \neq 0$ ?

Comment: Yes, for this very specific example of $T$ that works.  In more general words, we can show that $\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\2\end{pmatrix}$ is not an element of $T$'s range, [for example with row reduction](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=row+reduce+%7B%7B1,-1,0,0%7D,%7B0,1,-1,1%7D,%7B-1,0,1,2%7D%7D) and so there is no $v$ such that $Tv$ will equal $\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\2\end{pmatrix}$ and in particular no $S$ or $u$ such that $T(S(u))$ will equal that either.

Comment: Nice! thanks alot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire $S$ thing is a distraction.

As pointed out in the comments, you can start by proving that $\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 2\end{pmatrix} \notin T(\mathbb{R^3})$, where $T(\mathbb{R^3})$ just means the image of $T$. In other words, the equation system $T\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\\ z\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 2\end{pmatrix}$ has no solutions.

OK, so now we know that $T$ cannot transform anything into $\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 2\end{pmatrix}$, whether that "anything" is the image of a vector by $S$ or not

Answer (score 1):

Let $S\begin{pmatrix}-2\\ 0\\2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}$.

Given
\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
(T\circ S)\begin{pmatrix}-2\\ 0\\2\end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\ 
2\end{pmatrix} \\
T\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\2\end{pmatrix} \\
\begin{pmatrix}x_1-x_2\\ x_2-x_3\\x_3-x_1\end{pmatrix} &= \begin{pmatrix}0\\ 1\\2\end{pmatrix}
\end{split} \label{1} \tag{1}
\end{equation}

$\ref{1} \implies $

$x_1 = x_2 \label{1a} \tag{1a}$

$x_2-x_3=1 \label{1b} \tag{1b}$

$x_3-x_1=2 \label{1c} \tag{1c}$

Combining $\ref{1a}$, $\ref{1b} \implies x_1-x_3=1 \implies x_3-x_1=-1$ which contradicts with $\ref{1c}$. Hence such a transformation $S$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Good complement to my answer! Upvote!